# Add Icon to Visual Studio 2008-Built Class Lib DLL?

Tags: visual-studio, icons

I have a .ico that I want to add to several class library DLL projects, using Visual Studio Pro 2008. For each project, I added the ico, set the built type to 'embedded resource' and set the icon in the project prefs page. Still the icon is the default.

What did I miss?

Thanks.

Comment: I didn't think DLL files could have their own icon shown in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DLLs can't have icons assigned, they are associated with the file system and go by what icon is assigned to all DLLs.

It is a global OS thing...